# How to get rid of this default splash screen?

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

I've tried adding splash screens to my app, and while they do show before the main activity, this screen also always shows no matter what:

[image: pic]

Here is the code for MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements WelcomeFragment.StartQuestions, QuestionFragment.QuestionsAnswered {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "***************************", "*****************************");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadingIcon = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingIcon);
    loadingIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    checkInternetConnection();

    showWelcomeScreen();
}
}
```

showWelcomeScreen():

```
public void showWelcomeScreen(){
    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

    if (fragment == null){
        fragment = new  WelcomeFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    } else {
        fragment = new  WelcomeFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true" android:id="@+id/loadingIcon"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In MainActivity, I have already specified the removal of the top bar:
`this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

The app itself doesn't have the bar. Any activity that I place as being default in the manifest (acting as a splash screen) is nevertheless proceeded by the screen shown above when the app is launched.

Comment: Post your main activity code.

Comment: You will need to add relevant code to your question for anyone to help you

Comment: Sorry. I assumed this was a default screen everyone got regardless of their activity code

Comment: post `showWelcomeScreen()`.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html this will show you how to hide the status bar (assuming that's what you want to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Android will **always** attempt to show something using only the attributes of your theme before your Activity actually loads.

In fact, the [correct way to build a splash screen](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd) involves taking advantage of that fact and customizing your theme such that what displays during this time *is* your splash screen.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for